# Magento 2 product page price rounding up on new store view

Tags: price, magento2.2.2, product-prices

I've created 2 store view under 1 `wesbites->stores`

> store view 1 = default has Euro currency.
>
> store view 2 = Swiss has Swiss franc currency.

I've added a product on both store view now that costs 9.99 for both currencies.

But the Swiss store view rounds up CHF 10.00 I am missing any settings?

I can see that it's using javascript as the DOM data is correct as the price also flicker from 9.99 to 10.00

[image]

By the way I've added 1 to 1 in currency rates:

[image]

Comment: **@Juliano Vargas**, Have you found what causes this behavior?

Comment: @Carloscody I Don't remember what I have done I found this issue in my localhost test environment but since then I have change version with fresh installation. But I think it only happened because I had currency conversion on 1 to 1 .I might try again at some point.

Answer (score 0):

@Juliano Vargas, Have you found what causes this behavior?

EDIT: I've fixed this by deleting a setlocale(LC_ALL,"nl_NL") script which was placed in a custom module.